# Ошибка подключения с MS SQL в C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Сделал форму авторизации в C#, с полями логин и пароль. В БД MSSQL создан пользователь с логином и паролем. При попытке ввести эти данные через авторизацию в C# происходит ошибка. Что я делаю не так?
Вот строка подключения, которая используется в форме авторизации:

```
string connectionString = $"Data Source=SQL\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AutoFines;user id={tbLogin.Text};Password={tbPassword.Text}";
```

И ошибка:

> Not connected, error: При входе в систему пользователя "Stepan" произошла ошибка.

Так был создан логин для базы данных:

```
create login Stepan with password = '12345_Stepan'
create user Stepan for login Stepan
create role Admins
grant select, insert, update, delete, execute to Admins
grant backup database to Admins
execute sp_addrolemember 'Admins', 'Stepan'
```

Comment: смотрите логи сервера

Comment: А точно вы это всё в нужной БД проделали, а не в _master_? `USE [AutoFines]; SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals;` возвращает ли Stepan и Admins?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно значение поля Password стоит указать между одинарных кавычек?

```
string connectionString = $"Data Source=SQL\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AutoFines;user id={tbLogin.Text};Password='{tbPassword.Text}'";
```